# How does one reference the Trading View account balance or NAV. Is there a sysinfo. reference?

Tags: pine-script

I want to calculate position size off of current account balance or NAV balance in Trading View.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the strategy script, you can calculate the balance manually.

```
balance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
```